# Why $xy = 100$ does not represent a direct variation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

$xy = 100 $

$y = 100/x$

$x$ is not equal to $0$ and can be represented as $1\cdot x$

However I still do not understand on why $100/x$ does not represent a direct variation. Is it because of the use of division within the right side of the equation is not valid?

Comment: If this is something you encountered during a course of study, the first thing to do when you have such a question is to look up the definition of the thing you are asking about--and looking in your textbook or course notes is a much better way to look that up than asking a lot of strangers on the internet. If the answers below are not enough, then if you would edit the question so that it includes your definition of "direct variation," and explain why the answer is still not clear to you, you might get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visually speaking, a directly proportional relationship in the form $y=mx$ is a straight line. Thus the slope, which is $\frac{y}{x}$, must be constant for all $x$.

With $x=1, y=100$ and $x=2, y=50$, the slopes $\frac{y}{x}$ are $100$ and $25$ respectively. Since the slope is not constant, $xy=100$ is not directly proportional.

Comment: in fact it follows the square of  markup and margin.

Answer (score 0):

A direct relation is one of the form $y=mx$, but the relation here is not of that form – $x$ is being divided, not multiplied. Rather, it is an *inverse* relation.

Answer (score 0):

The relation is between the two variables $x$ and $y$. A direct variation means that when $x$ increases $y$ will increase too by an amount specified by the equation, for example:
$y=x$. If $x = 1$ then $y = 1$ and if $x$ increases to be $x=2$ then $y=2$ this is a direct variation and it may be represented like the $f(x) = x$.
Let's change the formula quite a bit $f(x) = x + 1$ this is the same as $y = x + 1$. If $x = 1$ then $y = 1 + 1 = 2$ and if $x = 2$ then $y = 2 + 1 = 3$. This is a direct variation.
Let's change the formula again $f(x) = x - 1$. If $x = 1$ then $y = 1 - 1 = 0$ and if $x = 2$ then $y = 2 - 1 = 1$. This is also a direct variation.
Again $f(x) = x \times 2$. If $x = 1$ then $y = 1 \times 2 = 2$ and if $x = 2$ then $y = 2 \times 2 = 4$. This is also a direct variation.
But what about $f(x) = \frac{1}{x} : x \ne 0$. If $x = 1$ then $y = \frac{1}{1} = 1$ and if $x = 2$ then $y = \frac{1}{2} = 0.5$. This is an inverse variation, as $x$ increases $y$ decreases or their product is a constant.
In the end a direct variation means that as $x$ increases $y$ increases, and an inverse variation means that as $x$ increases $y$ decreases.
Seeing graphs helps in understand so this is the graph of your equation $f(x) = \frac{100}{x}$:
[image: graph of the equation f(x) = \frac{100}{x}]